# How do I work the new "sites" page

Tags: support, status-completed, user-interface, footer

OK, we have a new footer. I hate it. Why? Because half the sites I go to are buried behind (more). And when I click that, I get something truly weird:

[image]

Why are half of the thingies blank?

Then if I click on one of the thingies, I get a slidy animation (I hate these, but I understand Kids These Days think they're great) and "fascinating" info about the site, but nothing to click on to, you know, **go to the site**:

[image]

I found a workaround which is to click on the "teaser" question and then use the header link to get to the main page of the site, but that can't be right.

What am I missing?

Comment: What browser/OS are you using? It certainly shouldn't look like that (and the sites page has been on stackexchange.com for quite a while now)

Comment: Windows 7, IE 9

Comment: Odd. I have a big "Visit Site" button on the pop out and I don't get the doubled bubbles issue either

Comment: I don't get blank squares when viewing the Grid view, and my big expanded squares include a "Visit Site" button which your screenshot is missing. Your screenshots are also missing some other things I have, like a Sort dropdown in the upper right. But if you click on the little squares in the upper-right you can change your view from a Grid to a List, which gives you direct access to the links, and that setting appears to be saved for when you come back to the page.

Comment: Confirming what you see on IE 9, windows 7. This isn't happening on other browsers (Opera, Firefox and Chrome tested).

Comment: You might be happier using the Sites list under the "Stack Exchange" popup in the top left-hand side of the page. It sorts your sites first.

Comment: @Oded you are "bombing" the browser with 211 simultaneous requests, probably older IE versions don't know how to digest such a thing so some requests are lost in limbo?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - That doesn't seem to be it. There is some DOM weirdness going on with IE 9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The strange double view on the grid view was caused by nested anchors - this bug was introduced when making the sites page friendly for non-js browsing (primarily for SEO).

Having nested anchor elements seems to have been handled fine by all currently supported browsers bar IE 9 (even IE 10 handles it fine), whose DOM parser seems to duplicate parent nodes of the nested node.

Regardless of what IE 9 actually does, I have fixed our markup so nested anchors are not there on page load, fixing the display issue.

Comment: Ah, that's much better! Site logos, Visit Site buttons, and no blank thingies. Appreciate the work that must have taken!

Comment: @KateGregory - It was mostly investigation of what was going on in IE 9... the HTML source and the webtools DOM view were in disagreement and it took a visit to the w3c validator to get a hint of what the issue was. Once I figured that out, a fix was straightforward.

Comment: I don't have a "Visit site" button either (Firefox 20.0.1). And I hate, hate, HATE the slidy graphic action thing which rearranges all the things you had just looked at and mentally filed away so you have to look at them again.

Comment: @Vicky - there is always the list view. And the `Visit Site` button is back now.

Comment: @Oded, ah, got the "Visit site" button now (that does help, although I still expect to be able to click on the site name to visit it!). Also, I see there is a list view but the first time I visited the /sites page I got the grid view and the presence of the list view was not exactly obvious, although I did find it eventually (but only after I had composed and then deleted a very ranty frustrated meta post about the grid view).

Answer (score 1):

You reached the "grid view" somehow. Go to the "list view":
https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#users

> [image]

Comment: List View is definitely better. Can we have "my rep on site" as a sort order?

Comment: I default to list view as well, but Grid View should work (and does on my browser)

Comment: @KateGregory that's actually how they're sorted in the "all sites" part of the global StackExchange dropdown at the top left of all pages.