# Could the StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™ show rep change in the site list?

Tags: feature-request, notifications, global-inbox, stack-exchange-button

Since the new footer was put into place I have started using the "all sites" dropdown pretty much exclusively to navigate through the sites. Some days, I just want to go through "my" sites looking at new questions. Other times, I want to see how my questions, answers, or comments have fared.

Surprisingly, I'm able to remember my rep on the dozen sites where I'm active. If I arrive and see my rep is 398 instead of 386, I can hover over my name to see what happened. But there are sites where I don't notice that my rep has changed until some time after the fact.

I think there's room in the list of sites for a number to show any rep changes - to be based on a timestamp or a "you saw this" that works just like the inbox and notification numbers, or possibly to just be "today" if that's less coding.

[image: rep change in super collider]

I would probably prefer showing blanks where you have no change, and it doesn't need to be red, I just did that to make it stand out.

Comment: "Since the new footer..." Do you mean header?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd which sites were removed from the footer?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Ahh!! I didn't know that. Thanks!

Comment: @TronicZomB Nick is correct, the sites just changed location and arranged in categories, but still for someone who was very used to the old design it might cause major headache. Personally didn't use the footer much but can understand the big impact on those who did.

Comment: @TronicZomB nope, footer. Time was all the non beta sites showed in the non beta footer and all the beta sites in the beta footer. Then they merged but some sites are hidden behind "more" links. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/177777/147247

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The new top bar (now site wide) takes care of most of this for me by showing all my recent rep changes across sites, though not in the all site dropdown. I'm going to mark this as [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) in my mind anyway.