# Get notified when you get upvoted/downvoted and option to disable this feature if you have a lotta rep

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

It would be cool if you could get notified when you get upvoted/downvoted. Users with high reputation could have the option to disable such feature. It would say on which question/answer you got (down/up)voted.

Comment: No? I am just suggesting good suggestions.

Comment: Go [here](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2782255/vlad-bondarenko?tab=reputation).  Press F5 occasionally.

Comment: My keyboard light goes down on my Mac Air. Nothing is happening.

Comment: You notice rep changes on your profile, beyond that this might be a notification too far. Still nothing wrong with an opt in option

Comment: Why am I so hated here? This is a legit feature I would love to see in the future. Y'all be trippin.

Comment: If every minor feature that anyone ever suggested for the SE software was implemented, the resulting printout of the source code would cover the state of Texas.

Comment: This is the best suggestion that has been suggested on the front page of Meta Stack Overflow. (IMO but since my opinion doesn't count)

Comment: What does this solve that a refresh doesn't?

Comment: @VladBondarenko You're not hated, people just don't like this one suggestion.  Apparently you'd like to see it, but others wouldn't.  Don't take it so personally.

Comment: Remember votes on meta can mean disaggrement. And everyone feels a little hated on meta from time to time

Comment: I MEAN AS in notification in the inbox in top left corner. You know when it lights up red?

Comment: @VladBondarenko Yes, we all get that.  We just don't want it, or think it's needed, and feel that the developers can better spend their time working on much more valuable features.

Comment: Sure. That would require you to click in order to see that happen. F5 is just as good. So - why is that better than F5?

Comment: Here, have a downvote. I certainly wouldn't want an annoying inbox notification for each upvote I get. And now imagine someone like Jon Skeet who gets tons of votes every day.

Comment: Admittedly this could come in handy for those who use several sites, its often weeks before I notice rep changes on game development. I'd want it strickly opt in though. Have your only +1

Comment: Nah, let's keep notifications for stuff that requires my attention. Extra rep is nice, but it's not something that requires my immediate attention.

Comment: @ThiefMaster - You must have missed the "can be disabled" portion of the feature request.

Comment: True, I did. The F5 argument is stupid anyway. Buy a proper keyboard which does not prevent you from using keys the way are supposed to be used :)

Comment: Exactly. Also, I edited my post read it before insulting me.

Comment: Sorry for my PC centrism. How insensitive of me. OK. How is this better than a simple refresh? And the fact that reputation changes are shown in real-time?

Comment: Nobody is insulting you. And we have read your post.

Comment: BECAUSE IT SHOWS ON WHICH QUESTION/ANSWER YOU GET VOTED! DANG!

Comment: On a Mac, F5 is spelled "command-R"

Comment: Beware moving from a legitimate (if unpopular) feature request into a rant

Comment: @VladBondarenko The reputation tab shows that same information.

Comment: So does a click on your profile reputation page. Or the profile popup.

Comment: Nvm.... Ppl are so rude.

Comment: They valued your opinion, they just disagreed

Comment: No I want to keep it so when **real** moderators come in they read how rude some members are to new users.

Comment: I can see at least **one** real moderator here.

Comment: @VladBondarenko Remember what I said about going from a legitimate (if unpopular) feature request into a rant. The whole point of suggesting a feature on meta is so people can agree/disagree and community opinion can be found

Comment: I meant admins. None of you are admins here. You can't rename this site or delete it, you can only do basic things.

Comment: Yal'l be trippin!

Comment: I guess being a Stack Exchange dev means nothing

Comment: @VladBondarenko Disagreeing with your proposal is not rude.  Thinking that it is is rather...unhealthy, actually.  You need to be able to deal with polite rejection without taking it personally (beyond the scope of just feature requests on a website).

Comment: Vlad, you might want to check out Oded's profile. He is an employee/developer at StackExchange, the maker of this site; therefore, he is as much of an admin as anyone would be on this site really.

Comment: You might like http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188869/could-the-stackexchange-multicollider-superdropdown-show-rep-change-in-the-sit which achieves what you want and could always use more support

Answer (score 23):

Basically you want to know when your reputation changed and why it changed.

This already exists - your reputation is updated in real-time. When you get an upvote it shows up in the header pretty much as soon as it happens.

If you hover over your profile, there is a popup detailing the posts that caused the reputation change. You can also click on the reputation to go directly to the reputation page where all reputation changes appear.

---

In conclusion - the feature request already exists.

Answer (score 8):

There is no need for such a feature. Extra reputation, though nice, is not something that requires your attention. Unlike comments for example. Granted, badges might not require your attention either, and I personally wouldn't mind them not causing a notification. But such events happen far less frequently than reputation changes.

And it's not as if reputation changes are hard to track. Each profile has an entire tab dedicated to them in all their glorious detail. Just refresh it occasionally. Or you know what; don't focus on reputation all that much.