# How do I report specific moderators to the actual owners of Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, moderators

There are several moderators that abuse their powers, and I want to seek justice and report them to the actual owners on this site. How can I accomplish this request?

Comment: I am going to assume this is because your last question was deleted because it was a duplicate of dozens of other questions.

Comment: @JoshC I guess it's because of the comments on this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197423/get-notified-when-you-get-upvoted-downvoted-and-option-to-disable-this-feature-i

Comment: I don't know, I think we're being a little generous as moderators by not destroying this account that you've created to work around your suspension here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/212483/vlad1k

Comment: Why bother?  [Modraters are just monkeys who has guns in there hands](http://i.stack.imgur.com/5G5dp.png).

Comment: @Won't how'd you get that pic of one of my former bosses? (LOL great pic!)

Answer (score 8):

Use the contact form at the bottom of every page, or the form at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact

Comment: I wrote an e-mail a long time ago and still got no response.

Comment: @Vlad Sending an email and using the contact form are not exactly the same thing

Comment: @VladBondarenko I suspect that a long time ago could be not that long. Keep in mind that they get a lot of emails so it could take some time before you will get a response.

Comment: @VladBondarenko you have only been on SO for 4 days, how do define a long time ago?

Comment: I had another account, but I lost the e-mail to it.

Comment: @apaul34208 The *person* has been here much longer. I can't comment any further on that, except that Vlad's explanation above... umm... isn't entirely complete.

Comment: @AndrewBarber I think I get what your saying, it explains the familiarity everyone seemed to have with him on his feature request...

Comment: @VladBondarenko [Lost the email to it, really?](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2102637/vlad-bondarenko)

Comment: @vlad If you lost the email, how do you know they didn't answer?

Comment: @user000001 D'oh! ;)

Comment: @AndrewBarber why haven't you guys burned this account as well?

Comment: @apaul34208: BOOM!  A punishing blow was dealt!

Comment: @Won't What Boom?

Comment: @apaul34208 See [Brad's comment on the question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197431/how-do-i-report-specific-moderators-to-the-actual-owners-of-stack-overflow#comment624750_197431)

Comment: @AndrewBarber Accounts 1 & 2 were suspended why not account 3? Apparently said generosity wasn't appreciated.

Comment: @apaul34208 At this point, we're probably going to let the Community Managers handle Vlad.